# Custom providers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: implementation, membership-provider, asp.net-mvc-5

Am new at ASP.NET MVC development.

For my [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) 5 Internet application I have created a custom [membership-provider](/questions/tagged/membership-provider) as my user-related [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) in my [database](/questions/tagged/database) contains additional columns which are not supported by the out-of-the-box [membership-provider](/questions/tagged/membership-provider) provided by ASP.NET ([simplemembership](/questions/tagged/simplemembership))

I'm more or less following the implementation method of this blog, [Implementing your own RoleProvider and MembershipProvider in MVC 3](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx) (*though I know that I'm working with MVC* ***5***).

In the blog at the section titled "Modifying the AccountController to use our new Providers" he inserts the following code in the `Initialize` method of his `AccountController`

```
[C#]
public LocalBankMembershipProvider MembershipService { get; set; }
public LocalBankRoleProvider AuthorizationService { get; set; }

protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    if (MembershipService == null)
        MembershipService = new LocalBankMembershipProvider();
    if (AuthorizationService == null)
        AuthorizationService = new LocalBankRoleProvider();

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

The above allows the author of the blog to use his custom membershipprovider's methods in that controller.

If following this bloggers example of how to implement a custom membershipprovider is pretty much the way to go, I was wondering if I have to initialize my custom providers in each and every Controller or does there exist a more elegant way of implementing it in my Controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a MVC 5 project I would recommend looking into using [ASP.NET-IDENTITY](http://www.asp.net/identity) rather a custom membership provider. It is easily customizable.